# how to make full screen image in flutter(images from firestore)?

Tags: image, flutter, fullscreen

i am bit stuck. i am displaying user image uploads inside a gridview .how can i make them go fullscreen on tap? i have checked out the Hero widget but i am not sure how to implement it in my case?

this is how my grid view looks like.

```
_buildDisplayPost()  {
if (_displayPosts== 0) {
  //grid
List<GridTile> tiles = [];
_posts.forEach((post) => tiles.add(_buildTilePost(post)),);
return GridView.count(
    crossAxisCount:3,
  childAspectRatio: 1.0,
  mainAxisSpacing: 2,
  crossAxisSpacing: 2,
  shrinkWrap: true,
  children: tiles,

);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing full-screen Container with image in it

Comment: This answer doesn't provide useful information.add some code or more explanation